# Excel Drop Down List Automatically Changes Product Name to Code

Tags: excel

seeing if you can help me with created an excel sheet

I would like a sheet that calculates ebay/paypal fees

Column A Purchase price
Column A will be the purchase price

Column B Ebay Fees
I would like a dropdown column with the ebay fees on column B

the dropdown will state the categories, and once clicking on a categories the percentage base on my selling price will get inputed in the cell
the categories are as follows:

- 4% Computers/Tablets & Networking, Video Game Consoles
- 6% Consumer Electronics and Cameras & Photos
- 7% Musical Instruments & Gear/ Coins & Paper Money
- 8% Motors Parts & Accessories
- 9% Clothing Shoes & Accessories Collectibles/Home & Garden/Camera & Photo Accessories/Cell Phone Accessories/All other Categories

Column C Top Rated Selling Discount
dropdown that will say 
Yes, No
If click on the dropdown Yes, 
Calculate seller fees with a 20% discount

On Column D Paypal Fees
the dropdown will say ($0 to $3000) ($3000 to $10,000) ($10,000)
and the fees will be calculated on Column C, based on selling price
paypal fees
- 2.9% + $.30 ($0 to $3000) 
- 2.5% + $.30 ($3000 to $10000) 
- 2.2% + $.30 ($10,000+)

Column E Shipping Fees

Column F
All items calculated

Thank you all in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With a reference array such as shown in K4:L8 the ColumnK part can be used applied for the validation of B2 and the relevant percentage as shown below in B3, with a formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$K$4:$L$8,2,0)
```

[image: SO19750887 example]

and something similar for the other required values.